# 404 in RESPONSIVE FileManager's Java Large File Uploader

Tags: file-upload, socialengine, responsive-filemanager

With SocialEngine's RESPONSIVE FileManager-based file uploader, itself a plugin component for the rich text editor, we are having a problem whereby when a user clicks "JAVA Upload (big size files)" the uploader frame loads a 404 error.

In the error log, the following line is the only indication I have for this problem:

```
/filemanager/dialog.php?type=4&descending=false&crossdomain=1&lang=en&akey=key
```

So it's not immediately obvious what framework or plugin Responsive FileManager expects to encounter which it can't actually find, or for that matter, where it's looking to find it. (I have RTFM but there is nothing about configuring the Java uploader in the manual. I have also tried reading the dialog.php source code but I couldn't find anything particularly useful when I did so.)

It may perhaps be looking for the file wjhk.jupload.jar in the
   filemanager/uploader/
directory. But I'm not sure why it can't find that file, or why it gets an error when it attempts to do so.

Surely I am not the only person to have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

SocialEngine doesn't come with a Java uploader at all, and its largely advised against using java for file uploading on the web.

It sounds like work of a 3rd party plugin (that might be misconfigured?). Check all your plugin files and make sure they were all uploaded to your server. Its also possible that your host disallows .jar files as they tend to be vectors for abuse. So it is worth contacting them.

Finally, contact the original developer of the plugin with your issue.